# Sitecore pipeline on URL with extension

Tags: iis, sitecore

I have a processor inserted in the *httpRequestBegin* pipeline.
And I have a WebApi controller setup for the url `/_api/user/{username}`

If I invoke this endpoint with a username that doesn't contain a `'.'` everything works fine. My controller is hit and everything is right and dandy.

However if the username contains a `'.'` such as an email address the pipeline isn't hit, but the WebApi controller is hit.

Is there some way to make sure the pipeline is invoked even though there is a `'.'` in the path?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this setting : < setting name="**IgnoreUrlPrefixes**"
 contains the **"."**

There is a processor called **IgnoreList** in the < **preAuthenticateRequest** > which if matches with the setting, aborts the pipeline.

And that is when your WebAPi Controller gets invoked.

Can you check that please in your showconfig.aspx ?

What i would also suggest is try re-ordering the processor you wrote. Patch it somewhere a little to the top inside < **httpRequestBegin**   > and if it works, then there is a pipeline below that might be causing the **"."** issue .

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."